# PHP unable to decode ASCII character

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii

I am investigating an issue where the browser is sending data to Apache(2.4) / PHP (7.2 Mac) and PHP is unable to decode some bytes into a printable character.  The character is '-' (the hexidecimal value 2D is given when the character is copied and pasted into https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php and ASCII hex translated here - https://ascii.cl/) but is displayed as ��� by PHP.

MariaDB displays the character fine and reports the length of the data source's column value as 250 characters.  The data is collected by PHP PDO and passed to an HTML form and used as a value for a text input form. The character displays fine in the HTML dom.  However, when the POST data is submitted back through Apache to PHP, PHP says the string length is 251 characters, and then subsequently breaks my string length sanitizer.

I found a short Python command to see the binary. I copied and pasted the character out of `Sequel Pro` and put it into this script.

```
import binascii
bin(int(binascii.hexlify('-'), 16))
'0b101101'
```

The history of the encoding is that it was from a Google Docs document, downloaded as .txt, opened in Mac Text Edit and saved with 'UTF-8' encoding, then passed through python into a MySQL database, back out through PHP to HTML and submitted back to PHP.

I have replaced the character in the database with another character '–' (hex value e28093) with binary output below, and everything works fine.

```
 bin(int(binascii.hexlify('–'), 16))
'0b111000101000000010010011'
```

Any ideas on why PHP fails to correctly recognize original character and reports the string length as +1 compared to MySQL? I assume that PHP should be able to handle all ASCII characters properly.

UPDATE:

When I print the original string (that is unprintable) out in the HTML dom (before posting back to PHP) the string length is reported as 249 characters and the '-' character is printable.

Comment: Are you sure there is no white space or new line character at the end?

Comment: I'm sure.  @Wiimm answer so far understands and explains the situation as I'm experiencing it.

Answer (score 0):

This '–' is `&ndash;` or U-2013. If it is delivered as ASCII, than 3 ASCII chars are send: 0xe2 0x80 0x93. The first code is `â` in ASCII 8bit, but undefined in standard ASCII (7bit). The other 2 chars are controls in ACII 8-bit. So 3 "?" are ok.

Anyway, you said, that the standard munis sign is also delivered as 3 "?". That is very unusual. Please proof this again.

Comment: No, the standard minus sign is not delivered as 3 "?", it works well.  I will change the OP to clarify that fact.

Comment: So, that may explain why when printed before output to the DOM, the str_length is 249, and when returned from the DOM the string length is 251.  But (1) why does the database report the string length as 250, (2) are you saying that the browser, despite receiving ASCII 8-bit returns the ASCII as 7-bit?